# Does django testing have a breakDown() similar to setUp() that is ran after all tests complete?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I am running some tests in django but they depend on a response from an outside service. For instance,
I might create a customer and wish to acknowledge it has been created in the outside service.

Once I am done with testing I want to remove any test customers from the outside service.

Ideally, there would be a method similar to `setUp()` that runs after all tests have completed.
Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of either [**`unittest.TestCase.tearDown`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) or [**`unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass)

**`tearDown(...)`** is the method gets called immediately after the test method has been called and the result recorded.

but, the **`tearDownClass(...)`** is gets called after tests in an individual class have run. ***That is, once per test class***.

IMO, using `tearDownClass(...)` method is more appropriate since ***you may not need to check/acknoledge the external service after search test cases of the same class***

Answer (score 1):

So Django's testing framework uses a Python standard library module, [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest). This is where the `setUp()` method comes from.

This library contains another method `tearDown()` that is called immediately after the tests are run. More info can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown)